# Is true Layer 2 access possible with docker container?

Tags: networking, docker

All the container networking examples I saw seems to provide container a L3 network which means it is on a separate L2 network from host. Bridge interface also seems to for L2 network between containers only.

Is it possible to launch a docker container such that it has full Layer 2 access. For example, to run tcpdump within the container to capture packet of a specific host interface?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Launch a container with [`--network host`](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) and it’ll not get its own network namespace. This has massive security implications.